# PHP Returning Data Type with Switch vs If Else

Tags: php, if-statement, types, switch-statement

I'm trying to track down why the if/else logic returns the correct datatypes versus the switch that does not.

IF/ELSE:

```
$value = false;
var_dump($value);

if(is_int($value)) {
  echo "INT";
} elseif (is_bool($value)) {
  echo "BOOL";
} elseif (is_null($value)) {
  echo "NULL";
} else {
  echo "DEFAULT";
}
```

SWITCH:

```
$value = false;
var_dump($value);

switch ($value) {
  case is_int($value):
    echo "INT";
    break;        
  case is_bool($value):
    echo "BOOL";
    break;
  case is_null($value):
    echo "NULL";
    break;
  default:
    echo "DEFAULT";
}
```

I'm not using strict comparison in the if/else. Not sure what's going on. Anyone?

Comment: That's not how `switch` statements work. Check [switch docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: If you wanted your switch statement to work .. You nee to `switch gettype($value)` --  Which checks the **type** of variable you have against the entire statement...  then `case 'boolean':` for example would check for a `boolean`.

Comment: If the `switch` argument `$value` is `false` `case` must evaluate to `false`. `is_int($value)` is `false` so it `echo`s `'INT'`.

Comment: Try doing `switch (true)` and leave the rest as you have it to evaluate if one of the cases is `true`. Should make it to `BOOL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted your switch statement to work .. You nee to `switch (gettype($value))` -- Which checks the type of variable you have against the **entire statement**... then `case 'boolean':` for example would check for a `boolean`

A literal translation of how that would look in your case is:

```
$value = false;
var_dump($value);

switch (gettype($value)) {
  case 'integer':
    echo "INT";
    break;        
  case 'boolean':
    echo "BOOL";
    break;
  case 'NULL':
    echo "NULL";
    break;
  default:
    echo "DEFAULT";
}
```

With the following `types` being what you can check for:

```
boolean
integer
double
string
array
object
resource
NULL
unknown type
```

Comment: @l'L'l Good catch on the parens -- Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
switch ($variable) {
case <expression>:
    ...
    break;
}
```

it's equivalent to writing:

```
if ($variable == <expression>) {
    ...
}
```

So your cases are analogous to writing

```
if ($value == is_int($value)) {
```

which is not the same as

```
if (is_int($value)) {
```

While I personally consider it poor form, some people like writing:

```
switch (true) {
case is_int($value):
    ...
    break;
case is_bool($value):
    ...
    break;
...
}
```

Comment: I've seen it done as you show in your example and in my comment, why do you feel it's poor form? Does it go against some sort of coding principle (I am not trained in computer sciences, so I honestly ask for pure curiosity, not to harass you)?

Comment: It just seems backwards to me, and it gains nothing over the usual `if/elseif`.

Comment: Personally I feel this should be the accepted answer as it gives both an explanation why it doesn't work, and how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`switch` compares a value to cases, this is how your code is executed

```
$value = FALSE;

var_dump(is_int($value)); // Gives FALSE

switch ($value) {
  // PHP runs is_int first and it returns FALSE
  // It becomes "case FALSE:" (Which is correct, $value is FALSE)
  // So INT is printed
  case is_int($value): 
....
```

The correct way to check for a type using `switch` is in [@zak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50123823/2595450).

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I think it's misleading when you say "your code works as intended" because it's not working as it was intended. It was intended to work as they describe, the same as the `if/else` example. It is working correctly as it is written and how you describe.  The script is working properly, just not how they wanted it to / thought it should work. Semantics really...

Comment: @Rasclatt I see, I think "as intended" should be replaced with "as designed", or just removed.

Comment: Yeah I think what you are saying now is better because now it's explaining what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

The most modern approach since PHP8 is to implement [`match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php).

This offer a most concise syntax with a returned value which can be echoed or stored in a variable without the messy `return` or `break` commands.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/O9g82))

```
$tests = ['foo', 1, '1', 1.5, false, null, [], true];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo "\n" . json_encode($test) . "\t: ";
    echo "(actual: " . gettype($test) . ")\t";

    echo match(gettype($test)) {
        'integer' => 'is_int',
        'double'  => 'is_float/is_double',
        'string'  => 'is_string',
        'NULL'    => 'is_null',
        'boolean' => 'is_boolean',
        default   => 'is_somethingelse'
    };
}
```

Output:

```
"foo"   : (actual: string)  is_string
1       : (actual: integer) is_int
"1"     : (actual: string)  is_string
1.5     : (actual: double)  is_float/is_double
false   : (actual: boolean) is_boolean
null    : (actual: NULL)    is_null
[]      : (actual: array)   is_somethingelse
true    : (actual: boolean) is_boolean
```