# Convert multiple if statements to a match() statement

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Is it possible to replace all `if` conditions with a `match` construct?

If yes, how to do it?

```
$a = 1;
$b = 1.2;
$c = "xopa";
 
function filter($massive) { 
    foreach($massive as $items){
        if(is_integer($items)){
            echo "integer - {$items} <br>";
        }
     
        if(is_double($items)){
            echo "floating point number - {$items} <br>";
        }
     
        if(is_string($items)){
            echo "string - \"{$items}\" <br>";
        }
    }
}
 
filter([$a, $b, $c]);
```

Comment: Relevant: [PHP Returning Data Type with Switch vs If Else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74257147/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with **match** condition shortly like this:

```php
<?php

$a = 1;
$b = 1.2;
$c = "xopa";
 
function filter($massive) {
     
    foreach($massive as $item){
        echo match(gettype($item)){
            
            'integer' => "integer - $item",
            'floot' => "float - $item",
            'string' => "string - $item",
            default => 'other type - '.$item
        }.'<br>';
    }
}

echo filter([$a,$b,$c]);
```

Comment: in my case, the match construct requires less resources than if ?

Comment: Yes, match use like switch-case   . Therefore conditions are shortly.

Comment: As I understand it, if there are few conditions, then it is better to use if, and if there are many conditions, then it is better to use match?

Comment: yes that is).  But also it is your choose. Better way is with few resource more job)